# mac: command not found: mongod

Tags: mongodb, macos

I installed mongodb by brew on my MacOS as the mongodb official documentation, but I tried to run MongoDB manually as a background process, use command "mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf --fork". Then the terminal displayed the message is : command not found: mongo.

Did I miss any steps?

Answer (score 0):

The above error appears when **mongodb** executable is not included in the **PATH** environment variable.

MongoDB gets installed to **/usr/local/bin/mongod**

The command 'mongod --config /usr/local....' will work only if '/usr/local/bin' is included in PATH.

**How to fix the problem?**

The problem can be fixed in 2 ways -

1. **Calling the mongod command with full path**

> /usr/local/bin/mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf --fork

2. **Adding '/usr/local/bin' to PATH**

> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin

Run the above command or add the above line to the end of **.zshrc** file and **.bash_profile** file and execute **mongodb** command in **a new terminal window**.

> mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf --fork