# Run mongod in ZSH shell on Mac and and get command not found

Tags: mongodb, zsh

I'm trying to run `mongod`in my terminal, but I'm getting a `command not found`. I've consulted other questions on this issue, including this these: 
[mac: command not found: mongod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59946920/mac-command-not-found-mongod)
[Mongod: Command Not Found (OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862808/mongod-command-not-found-os-x)

But the solutions have not worked for me.

Here is the full path of mongod:

```
/Users/danno/mongodb/bin/mongod
```

In .zshrc, I've tried two scripts, but neither one works:

Attempt 1 (from other Stack Overflow questions):

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/mongodb/bin"
```

Attempt 1 (My own guess):

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/danno/mongodb/bin/mongod"
```

I've restarted the terminal multiple times to no avail.

From the terminal, I'm trying to run:

```
mongod --dbpath=/Users/danno/mongodb-data
```

Getting a command not found while running that and also just with `mongod` alone.

Is something wrong with my pathing?

Comment: Try `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/danno/mongodb/bin/`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to do this step:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

It is better to put $PATH at the end.

I hope this will help. [Additional options](https://dev-qa.com/185612/the-mongod-command-not-found) can be found in the post and the video.